# AngularJS directive not working where element have a binding value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive to show/hide element based on something. But it doesn't work where element have binding to some value. I want my directive still working in this condition.

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope){
  $scope.color = "red";
})


.directive('xred', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var role = 0;
      if (role === 0) element.css('display', 'none');
    }
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <!-- where I hard code 'blue', xred directive is working-->
  <span xred style="color: blue"> Blue (should hide) </span>
  
  <!-- where I bind color, xred directive is not working.-->
  <span xred style="color: {{color}}"> Red (should hide) </span>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question, but using [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) it seems to work:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope){
  $scope.color = "red";
})


.directive('xred', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var role = 0;
      if (role === 0) element.css('display', 'none');
    }
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <!-- where I hard code 'blue', xred directive is working-->
  <span xred style="color: blue"> Blue (should hide) </span>
  
  <!-- where I bind color, xred directive is not working.-->
  <span xred ng-style="{color: color}"> Red (should hide) </span>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set a style using Angular's interpolation it now keeps track of it's attribute value itself and any change you made by touching directly the element will be overridden by Angular anytime (like setting `display: none` which basically just modifies the `style` attribute which is then overridden by `color: {{color}}`).

So in your case try not writing directly into `style` attribute and use [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) or [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead.

I added just class `hidden` to your example and add/remove it to show/hide your element.

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope){
  $scope.color = "red";
})


.directive('xred', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var role = 0;
      if (role === 0) {
          element.addClass('hidden');
      }
    }
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <!-- where I hard code 'blue', xred directive is working-->
  <span xred style="color: blue"> Blue (should hide) </span>
  
  <!-- where I bind color, xred directive is not working.-->
  <span xred style="color: {{color}}"> Red (should hide) </span>
  
</div>
```